# Generate a PDF with a full DIN A4 background image

Tags: css, image, pdf

I have an image which is 2480x3508px - in Photoshop it says also 595.pt and 841.9pt or 21cm * 29,7cm.

When I insert this image as a background image in my template with the following dimensions and generate a pdf I get weird results:

```
<style type="text/css">

    @page {
        margin: 0mm;
        size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    }

    body {
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
        background-image: url('voucher_AF_A4.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

The result looks like this: http://d.pr/i/ZzN2 - which is not the picture I have. Do you know why the image is much larger than the DINA4 even when the image has the same dimensions?

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post also the template code?

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I use DomPDF to generate a PDF afterwards, this seems to have some issues.

Comment: If you are sure, that the image-proportion is valid you  can also do this:

background-size: 100% 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with something like:

```
@page {
    margin: 0mn;
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-image: url('voucher_AF_A4.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: 100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
```